# Leave audio at the remote computer

Tags: audio, remote-desktop

I have a server with some applications that need the audio to work.

The problem is that Remote Desktop switches audio driver to "Microsoft Rdp Audio Driver" no matter which choice I make under "Options / Local Resources / Audio".

How can I force Remote Desktop to NOT mess with the audio settings, since "Play on remote computer" does not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Need to invoke RDP in console mode

```
Start button -> run -> mstsc.exe /admin
```

(`/console` for certain OSs)

Answer (score 0):

[image]

This setting works for me connecting to a remote Windows 10 machine from Windows 10.

I'm surprised it doesn't work for you.

Comment: I'm not surprised that it works for you. A lot has happened in 10 years =)

Comment: That's why I posted an updated answer